# I'm trying to get the Followers of a specific user with Eloquent, from a many to many relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to create a function that returns all the followers of a specific user.
I tried using this method:

```
    public function getFollowers($id){
            $user=User::find($id);
            $followers=$user->followers();
            return response()->json([
                'data' => $followers,
            ]);
    }
```

But it returns this.

```
{
"data": {
    "withTimestamps": false
}
```

}

In my user model I have this functions:

```
public function following(){ //users that are followed by this user
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'followers', 'user_id', 'follower_id');
}
public function followers(){  //users that follow this user
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'followers', 'follower_id', 'user_id');
}
```

And the design of the tables are these:

Followers:
[image: followers table]

Users:
[image: Users table]

Comment: Have you tried `$followers = $user->followers;` instead of `$followers=$user->followers();` ?

Comment: try to user `$follower = $user->with('follower')->get()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change code to

```
public function getFollowers($id) 
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $followers = $user->followers()->get();
    return response()->json([
        'data' => $followers,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: omg It was so simple to only just add a ->get(). Thanks Davit